# Bringing CAD docs to Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, autocad

I am using AutoCAD Civil 3D 2016 and working on files with high mb's. To be specific, I am working on preparing a corridor for a railway alignment of 600 km in which I have to place contours, roads and every existing feature within the offset of 100 m.

What I want to know is, is it possible that when my drawing is completed in AutoCAD, I can bring it in to Photoshop or CoralDRAW so that while changing the plot scale I don't have to change the text size again and again?

Comment: Yes you can do this, on the other hand you may want to consider using illustrator.  On that note you can make autocad also do this without intervention. Besides a exported PDF allready has the same capability.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to print your CAD project to tif or pdf and than open it in Photoshop.